# SQL :Return some value even if there is no match

Tags: sql

I have sql query in which  I am passing students ids  'IN' clause.
If there is no record match with given id it does not return anything.
I want   the query return something like false or not exist etc  even if there is no record matching

// pseudo query   (for sake brevity , i am restricting query for one table , actual query involves other tables.)

```
Select student_id from STUDENTS  WHERE s.student_id in (?,?,?);
```

Comment: Does have Students table many rows or big data?

Answer (score 1):

Apply `OR is null`

```
Select s.student_id 
from STUDENTS   s
WHERE s.student_id in (?,?,?)
  or s.student_id is null;
```

If joining, use left join:

```
select s.student_id
from students s
left join othertable o
  on o.something = s.something
WHERE s.student_id in (?,?,?)
  or s.student_id is null;
```

And if student is on the right:

```
select s.student_id
from othertable o
left join students s
  on o.something = s.something
  and s.student_id in (?,?,?) -- we put this into the join clause so we don't need the "or is null"
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTs(Select student_id from STUDENTS  WHERE s.student_id in (?,?,?))
  BEGIN 
    Select student_id from STUDENTS  WHERE s.student_id in (?,?,?)
 END
  ELSE 
    select 0
```